# Is it a good practice to save data to a database from within another model? In Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `articles` and a `notifications` table. Whenever an article is successfully saved in the database, I send a notification to the user about it from within the model.

My question is...

Is it permissible in the MVC design to do this or should I use controllers for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, and you should probably *not* use a controller for this *unless* it is exclusively triggered by a request, or dependent on request parameters. In most cases, this is business logic that belongs in the model layer.

Alternatively, you could take a look at [observers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) if you want to keep the actions of saving the article and notifying the user decoupled from each other.